# Reseting Shiny app via fileInput (when the user browses new data)

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I am developing an app which requires data input from the user. I need the app to reset everything once the user clicks on the "Browse" button to upload new data (I think it's a bad practice to ask the user to reset everything via a separate button and then browse new data!). I hoped this code to work but it didn't! The "Browse" button removes nothing!

```
library(shiny)

x = 0.1
y = 0.1
df = data.frame(x,y) #Just define a simple dataset


ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  

  fileInput('datafile', 'Select your data CSV file',
            accept=c('csv', 'comma-separated-values','.csv')),
  
  tableOutput('table'),
  
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  
  output$table = renderTable({
    
    df
    
  })
  

  # 
  
  
  observeEvent(input$datafile, {
    
    output$table = NULL #This one didn't work
    df = NULL           #This one didn't work as well
    
    
  })
  
})

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This is just a minimal example code. Can someone help me to remove the previously entered variables via "Browse" button so the app will be fresh for the new data to come in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df` should be reactive so that it gets modified according to UI input.
You could use a `reactiveVal` updated after browsing a new file:

```
library(shiny)

x = 0.1
y = 0.1


ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  
  fileInput('datafile', 'Select your data CSV file',
            accept=c('csv', 'comma-separated-values','.csv')),
  
  tableOutput('table'),
  
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  df <- reactiveVal(data.frame(x,y))
  
  observe({
    file <- input$datafile
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
    
    req(file)
    validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a csv file"))
    
    df(read.csv(file$datapath, header = T))
  })
  
  output$table = renderTable({
    
    df()
    
  })
  
})
```

Comment: Ok maybe I couldn't correctly express what I meant. The code you wrote does overwrite previous dataframe, but I wanted to use Browse button as a tool to delete everything else in the app. Basically everything that is defined before should be removed just by browsing new data (here I don't even care about seeing the new data, I just want it to delete everything else as in my real app I want browing to refresh the app totally).

Comment: If the values are reactive, you can reset them in the code I provided. For example, instead of `df(read.csv(file$datapath, header = T))` you can use `df(NULL)` to clear `df`. You can do this with any reactive variable you want to reset.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved using reactiveVal(). This is what I really wanted to see:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  fileInput('datafile', 'Select your data CSV file',
            accept=c('csv', 'comma-separated-values','.csv')),
  textInput("txt", "Enter the text to display below:"),
  verbatimTextOutput("default"),
  tableOutput('table'), #This is just to check whether the variable will be deleted
  
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  X <- reactiveVal(c(1,3))
  Y <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  observe({
   
    Y(input$txt)
    
     
  })
  
  output$default <- renderText({Y() })
  output$table = renderTable({ #This is just to check whether the variable will be deleted
                           X()
    })
  
  
  
  observeEvent(input$datafile,{
    Y(NULL)
    X(NULL)
  })
  
})

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

"Browse" button is used as an action button to reset everything defined before clicking the button.